# Query that satisfies all conditions in an array

Tags: elasticsearch

The documents are stored in the form below in Elastic Research index.

mapping

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "data": {
        "type": "nested" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

first docs

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "value": "a"
        },
        {
            "value": "a"
        },
        {
            "value": "b"
        }
    ]
}
```

second docs

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "value": "a"
        },
        {
            "value": "a"
        },
        {
            "value": "a"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to return the document only when all values in the array are 'a' (second docs)

In this case, how should I make the query condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) searches nested field objects as if they were indexed
> as separate documents. If an object matches the search, the nested
> query returns the root parent document.

**When using a combination of bool query with `must` and `must_not`, it searches for each individual nested object and eliminates the objects that do not match, but if there are some nested objects left, that match with your query, you will get your results.**

Try out this below search query, where all the documents are discarded who have a nested object with the `b` value.

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "data",
          "query": {
            "term": {
              "data.value": "b"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64329782",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.0,
        "_source": {
          "data": [
            {
              "value": "a"
            },
            {
              "value": "a"
            },
            {
              "value": "a"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Search Query with the combination of multiple bool and nested queries:**

The below search query will also give you the required result.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "data",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "data.value": "a"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "data",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "data.value": "b"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will work... a document would be returned if it contains only one nested document `a` and no nested `b`... what about other values?

Comment: @Val I have tried the above search query, only on the index data provided by the user. And on that index data, I am getting the required result. As far as I know, there is no other generic way to achieve the required result.

Comment: What I'm saying is that the query works in that specific case, however, the question is `only when **all** values in the array are 'a'`... as far as I know, it doesn't say whether there can only be `a` and `b` nested values (in which case your query works) or also other values (in which case it would not work)

Comment: Yes, @Val makes sense  My query will work on the index data (2 sample document) provided by the user, where it will return the document containing all the `value: a`. If there is some other document having any other value apart from `a` and `b`, then some more clauses must be added in the query to make it work

Comment: @Val I am not sure, if there is any other way, to achieve the above use case, apart from a combination of multiple bool queries

Comment: We need to wait for the OP to state more precisely what the values can be

Comment: I agree with @Val here. I think people coming here are looking for a general solution. So I think its safe to assume that there are more values than just `a` and `b`

Comment: I figured it out. I will write an answer in a while. Sorry deadlins to meet 